# variable type in typescript

Tags: javascript, typescript

As when we declare a variable with type number then we cannot assign a string to that variable. My question is that why typescript do show error when we assign a object to variable of type number.

Comment: Just like strings are not numbers, objects are also not numbers. You cannot assign an object to a number.

Comment: Why did you expect that it *wouldn't* show an error?

Comment: @Alan its typo mistake . my question is that why do not show error when we assign a object to variable of type number

Comment: @jonrsharpe its typo mistake . my question is that why do not show error when we assign a object to variable of type number

Comment: @user3595398 can you provide an example?

Comment: @Alan loginData:  Number =0;
  login(data) {
    console.log(data); //{email: 'adf', password: 'saf'}
    this.loginData = data;
    console.log(this.loginData); // {email: 'adf', password: 'saf'}
  }

Comment: Then your question makes no sense, because it *does* show an error.

Comment: @jonrsharpe you can try it . it do not show error

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=let%20foo%3A%20number%3B%0D%0Afoo%20%3D%20%7B%7D%3B

Comment: ok thanks @jonrsharpe . but this thing works in angular 4 which also use typescript.

Answer (score -1):

> My question is that why typescript do show error when we assign a object to variable of type number

Code sample:

```
const foo: number = {}; // Error : Type {} is not assignable to `number`
```

## Reason

Because `{}` doesn't have all the methods that exist on a number e.g. `toPrecision`.